# Pass literal {} as an argument in find -exec

Tags: find

I was writing an answer to a question on Stack Overflow, and the answer involved a nested `for` loop similar to

```
for jpeg in **/foo.jpg; do
    d=${f%/foo.jpg}   # Directory containing foo.jpg
    for m4a in "$d"/*.m4a; do
        someCommand "$m4a" --arg "$jpeg" 
    done
done
```

I had this idea to make the whole thing into a single `find` command that used *another* `find` command in its `-exec` primary, something like:

```
find . -type d -exec test -f {}/foo.jpg \;
               -exec find {} -name '*.m4a' \
                             -exec someCommand ??? --args {}/foo.jpg \;
```

The problem is with the `???`. I would want to pass a literal `{}` to be used as an argument in the nested `find`'s `-exec` without the outer `find` replacing it with a directory name as it would with `{}/foo.jpg`.

The POSIX standard doesn't really say anything about passing a literal `{}` as an argument to a command. It only says

> If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change.

This would seem to preclude some sort of trickery involving `sh -c`, like

```
-exec sh -c 'someCommand {} --args "$1"' _ {}/foo.jpg \;
```

since `{}` may or may not be replaced by the outer `find`.

So, is there any way to nest `find` in this fashion?

Comment: My respect for the search function on Stack Exchange sites continues to drop. I'm pretty sure that question did not come up as a potential duplicate even when I was using a similar title.

Answer (score 2):

### Find does not have any escape mechanism

This fact will not allow you to insert `{}` inside an existing `-exec` and/or `-execdir` option.  The substitution is made with plain `strncpy()`.  The `exec`/`execdir` is performed inside GNU-find (which I'm using as reference) through `bc_push_arg`.  For the `{} +` form we have:

```
  /* "+" terminator, so we can just append our arguments after the
   * command and initial arguments.
   */
  execp->replace_vec = NULL;
  execp->ctl.replace_pat = NULL;
  execp->ctl.rplen = 0;
  execp->ctl.lines_per_exec = 0; /* no limit */
  execp->ctl.args_per_exec = 0; /* no limit */

  /* remember how many arguments there are */
  execp->ctl.initial_argc = (end-start) - 1;

  /* execp->state = xmalloc(sizeof struct buildcmd_state); */
  bc_init_state (&execp->ctl, &execp->state, execp);

  /* Gather the initial arguments.  Skip the {}. */
  for (i=start; i<end-1; ++i)
{
  bc_push_arg (&execp->ctl, &execp->state,
           argv[i], strlen (argv[i])+1,
           NULL, 0,
           1);
}
```

It just appends everything at the end, since you can't have more than one instance of `{}` in the `{} +` form.  And for the `{} ;` we have:

```
  /* Semicolon terminator - more than one {} is supported, so we
   * have to do brace-replacement.
   */
  execp->num_args = end - start;

  execp->ctl.replace_pat = "{}";
  execp->ctl.rplen = strlen (execp->ctl.replace_pat);
  execp->ctl.lines_per_exec = 0; /* no limit */
  execp->ctl.args_per_exec = 0; /* no limit */
  execp->replace_vec = xmalloc (sizeof(char*)*execp->num_args);


  /* execp->state = xmalloc(sizeof(*(execp->state))); */
  bc_init_state (&execp->ctl, &execp->state, execp);

  /* Remember the (pre-replacement) arguments for later. */
  for (i=0; i<execp->num_args; ++i)
{
  execp->replace_vec[i] = argv[i+start];
}
```

So we have `execp->ctl.replace_pat = "{}";`.  This is all in [`parser.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find/parser.c)

The above is substituted as:

```
  size_t len;               /* Length in ARG before `replace_pat'.  */
  char *s = mbsstr (arg, ctl->replace_pat);
  if (s)
    {
      len = s - arg;
    }
  else
    {
      len = arglen;
    }

  if (bytes_left <= len)
    break;
  else
bytes_left -= len;

  strncpy (p, arg, len);
  p += len;
  arg += len;
  arglen -= len;
```

In `bc_do_insert()` in [`buildcmd.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/buildcmd.c).

So no, there is no way of escaping the `{}`.  Yet, some versions of find will not substitute `{}/foo` but only `{}` itself so you may be able to use two different versions of find together with an `-exec sh -c 'someCommad {}'`.

Assuming that `gfind` is GNU-find and `afind` is AIX find you probably can achieve:

```
afind . -type d -execdir test -f foo.jpg \
        -exec sh -c 'gfind . -name "*.m4a" -exec someCommand {} \;' \;
```

But that would be a horrible hack.

### Decent workaround

The problem you are facing is that you are performing globing to get the all files of a type in a directory.  In other words, you are first finding a directory and globbing all files of that directory to be part of a *single command line*.

This is the kind of problem `-execdir` is meant to solve.  It will run the command in the directory that contain the found file.  For example:

```
$ mkdir -p a/a b/b c/c d e
$ touch a/a/foo.m4a b/b/foo.m4a
$ touch a/a/bar.m4a b/b/bar.m4a c/c/foobar.m4a
$ touch a/a/yay.jpg c/c/yay.jpg
$ find . -type f -name '*.m4a' -execdir test -e yay.jpg \; \
                               -execdir echo someCommand --arg yay.jpg {} +
someCommand --arg yay.jpg ./foobar.m4a
someCommand --arg yay.jpg ./bar.m4a ./foo.m4a
```

Moreover, I'm using the `{} +` form instead of the `{} ;` form for the `exec`.  This will place all files found (in the directory it is running in) into the same command line.

Note that the command did not run in `b/b` because the `test -e` prevented it.

Comment: I'm not looking for a workaround; I'm asking specifically about the syntactic issue.

Comment: @chepner - I don't think there is a syntactic way.  `-exec` family does not invoke a shell, it simply performs an `execvp()` after going through each argument and searching for the `{}` string to substitute.  Maybe you could compile a non-GNU find which would not substitute `{}` if it is not a single argument (i.e. `{}/foo.jpg` is not substituted by AIX/HP-UX find) and then call the non-GNU find from the `-exec` in the GNU find.  But that would be much more convoluted and even less intuitive to do.

Comment: I'm just surprised there isn't a work around, complex though it might be. Python, for instance, allows literal `{` and `}` in a format string by doubling them: `"{{{}}}".format("hi")` evaluates to `{hi}`.

Comment: @chepner - I went to savannah to check, but no GNU-find uses plain `strncpy()` to make the substitution, so there really is not escaping whatsoever.